# git return to original master after committing under detached head

Tags: git

I wanted to look at an older version of a file. I did a bad thing, checked it out on the master branch, creating a detached head, and then committed a new revision.

This resulted in a situation I do not understand. I could not figure out how to get back to the original repository - it appeared as if I had lost a number of commits.  After some searching I found that "reflog" could be used to find the SHA of a recent commit, then I checked out that SHA into a separate branch, and will be working from there until I understand the situation.

I am aware (now) that when checking out an older revision, it is good practice to do it on a branch. However, I think that I am starting to get the overall idea of git, and would like to understand what happened better.

My question:  can someone describe why I could not seem to go back to the original state of the repo by doing a "checkout master" or "reset --hard", and what is the right way to do this?

Here is the sequence of commands that led to the mystery state:

```
git checkout 343294f125 myfile.txt
git checkout -- myfile.txt
git checkout master myfile.txt
git add file2 
git commit
```

These steps do not seem to restore the original repository

```
git reset --hard
git checkout master
# git log still shows commits going back from 34329, not recent ones
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you did, but `git checkout master` is the correct way to return to the `master` branch.  If you really checked out `master` and you do not see the history you expect, then perhaps doing `git reset --hard` had some unintended consequences (do _not_ use hard reset to return to the original branch).

Comment: The sequence of commdns should not have led to detached HEAD. What did you run before these commands? Maybe something like `git checkout <commit>` or `git checkout <tag>`.

Comment: I believe the first command listed above caused the detached head. It is checking out an older version of a particular file:  "git checkout 343294f125 myfile.txt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of these commands lead to detached head state:

```
git checkout sha1 myfile.txt
git checkout -- myfile.txt
git checkout master myfile.txt
```

All these commands get the content of `myfile.txt` as of some revision, and none of them lead to detached head state.

The first one gets `myfile.txt` as of the revision `sha1`, puts in your working tree and adds to the index. This is useful when you want to restore specific files to some previous state.

The second command takes the file from the index. This is useful if you made some changes to the file, without adding the changes to the index, and you want to restore the file to its state on the index. Note that the index may be different from the last revision.

The third command takes the file from the `master` branch.

You get into a detached head state when you run checkout with only a sha1 or branch or tag, without specifying any files. That is, `git checkout sha1` (and no path arguments).

In this mode, Git puts the working directory in the state as in the specified sha1/branch/tag.

If you are in detached head state, you can get out of it with `git checkout`. You can either checkout some existing branch, or create a new branch from the detached head, effectively giving it a name, with `git checkout -b somenewbranch`.

Comment: I do not understand what I did to produce the situation then. Strange, because I recovered the sequence of commands by greping the history for "git" so it should be accurate. But it was certainly something supid I did. Anyway I understand better now.

Comment: @beginner probably you did `git checkout 343294f125` ?